# Why does Python import only once?

Tags: python, import, module, python-import

I was going through the `import` statement in Python and learnt that Python follows an import-only-once rule.

This means that two import statements in a given file referring to the same module won't reimport that module.

**I just wanted to know, what exactly would be the reason Python uses this rule? How does it any way make Python programs more efficient?**

At the end of the day, if a programmer imports the same module twice, he is responsible himself for the inefficiency (if any inefficiency is caused). How does two imports cause inefficiency?

Comment: When `import`ing again, prveviously `import`ed things like functions amd variables will be overwritten.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi What if they remain unchanged in the program. Then that won't count..

Comment: I think I got your point. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a package named `pkg` like:

```
print('importing...')

def hi():
    print('Hi')
```

even though you `import pkg` multiple times like

```
import pkg
import pkg
import pkg
```

you will see only one "importing..." string printed. Because Python already knows that `pkg` is imported, Python does not import the package again. What will happen if Python import the same package again? Wasting time for importing just to rewrite what is already on the memory.

If `pkg` is like:

```
print('importing...')

someone = 'there'

def hi():
    print('Hi, {}~'.format(someone))
```

you may want to import it multiple times due to the variable `someone`. Then you can do something like:

```
import sys

import pkg as pkg_1
sys.modules.pop('pkg')  # let Python not know the package is already imported

import pkg as pkg_2
sys.modules.pop('pkg')

pkg_1.someone = 'John Doe'
pkg_1.hi()

pkg_2.someone = 'Foo Bar'
pkg_2.hi()
```

It does not look good, right? Designing a package not necessarily to be imported multiple time like:

```
print('importing...')

def hi(someone):
    print('Hi, {}~'.format(someone))
```

is much better.

Answer (score 2):

1. `import` loads a package/module into memory in order to ensure access to its symbols. Once it is loaded it makes little sense to repeat it. It would be like learning a poem by heart several times in a row.
2. Multiple imports typically do not happen in a single file. They happen when a package consists of several files. Each file needs to import all of its depencencies, the progammer has no other choice. Frequently used modules are thus referenced many times quite naturally. As explained above, it is fully sufficient to import only once.

Answer (score 1):

i put  import twice in my code and i realized that when you put import  twice in  your document just the first code run and the otherrun  just like a comment !
when  you import once a module  it occur all the document it help you  don't overwrite import in your documention